# Vue.js, try to upload a single file asynchonously (Vue.js / Node.js)

Tags: node.js, file-upload, vue.js

My goal looks simple, but I try to upload a single file, asynchronously, using Vue.js (and axios, for instance). 
It seems to work as long as I don't try to handle the upload at server side. When I 'plug' my server code I get error 500 and no clue to find out what's going on.

My HTML :

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" v-on:change="onFileChange">
</form>
```

My Vue.js script :

```
onFileChange: function(event) {
  var image = new Image();
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
    console.log('file readed : ');

    axios.post('/upload_file', reader.result, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
});
reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

},

My Node.js server code :

```
router.post('/upload_file', function(req, res) {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.IncomingForm().parse(req) // this line create Error #500
    .on('file', function(name, file) {
        console.log('Got file:', name);
    })
    .on('field', function(name, field) {
        console.log('Got a field:', name);
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Got a error:');
        next(err);
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        res.end();
    });
  res.end();
});
```

I spent a day on this, file upload is just my nightmare, any help will be appreciated (and sorry for my english).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the node part. But in Vue I would do this:

```
onFileChange: function(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    reader.addEventListener('load', function(data) {
    axios.post('/upload_file', {
        data: data.target.result
    });
});
```

So basically add "data" as parameter in die file readers event listener function and "data.target.result" to transfer the file data.